# rich edit class

Tags: c, winapi

```
HWND hEdit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "EDIT", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | ES_READONLY | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL, 0, 0, width, height, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_MAINEDIT, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
```

Well, that's how I create an (readonly) edit (textbox) control.
How can I create a RichEdit control? I mean, what's the richedit's class name?

I want to use richedit because it has CatText or something like that so I can **append** text to it, instead of copying it's text - reallocating it and adds appending and finally set the edit's text (I could do in that way, but it's awkward way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Creating a Rich Edit Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787877.aspx#creating_re_control) (on MSDN)

Comment: thanks adf88, I succeeded LoadLibrary("Riched32.dll"); HWND hEdit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "RichEdit", "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | ES_READONLY | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL, 0, 0, width, height, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_MAINEDIT, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
( how do I put a code tag? )

Answer (score 0):

RichEdit is implemented in several different dll's depending on the OS and version of the control, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787873%28VS.85%29.aspx) has a list of dll's and versions...